# Can I use Combiner to compute average in a mapreduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, average, reducers, combiners

I want to implement a mapreduce job that reads parquet files with the following schema:

```
{
  optional int96 dropoff_datetime;
  optional float dropoff_latitude;
  optional float dropoff_longitude;
  optional int32 dropoff_taxizone_id;
  optional float ehail_fee;
  optional float extra;
  optional float fare_amount;
  optional float improvement_surcharge;
  optional float mta_tax;
  optional int32 passenger_count;
  optional binary payment_type (UTF8);
  optional int96 pickup_datetime;
  optional float pickup_latitude;
  optional float pickup_longitude;
  optional int32 pickup_taxizone_id;
  optional int32 rate_code_id;
  optional binary store_and_fwd_flag (UTF8);
  optional float tip_amount;
  optional float tolls_amount;
  optional float total_amount;
  optional float trip_distance;
  optional binary trip_type (UTF8);
  optional binary vendor_id (UTF8);
  required int64 trip_id;
}
```

The main object of the job is to compute the average speed of the taxi in the trips for each hour a day (0->23).

My ***Mapper*** class computes the speed for each pickup hour so it delivers the following couple ***(hour, speed)***.

The ***Reducer*** class normally should compute the average of speeds for each hour.

However I am wondering whether I can use a combiner class to facilitate the data precessing because I learned that combiner classes can only be used with commutative and associative operations and this is not the case for average right?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combiner can assist with calculating averages. You basically want to use the combiner to give you a running total that you can use in the reducer to calculate the average.

As input the combiner would get `(hour, (speed, 1))`, and as output it should produce `(hour, (sum_speed, num_records))`. The reducer can then calculate the average for each hour by dividing `sum_speed` by `num_records`.

For example, if combiner 1 receives as input:

```
(1, (50, 1))
(1, (20, 1))
(1, (10, 1))
(23, (16, 1))
```

then it would output:

```
(1, (80, 3))
(23, (16, 1))
```

and if combiner 2 receives as input:

```
(1, (20, 1))
(23, (40, 1))
```

then it would output:

```
(1, (20, 1))
(23, (40, 1))
```

the reducer would then sum them again before dividing:

```
(1, (80+20, 3+1)) = (1, (100, 4)) = (1, 25) 
(23, (16+40, 1+1)) = (23, (56, 2)) = (23, 28)
```

giving you your answers in the form of `(hour, average_speed)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am thinking of this solution however the couple (sum_speed, num_records) should be the value of the mapper output as well because the combiner and the mapper must have the same key/value types as I know.

Comment: Sorry you're right. I haven't done MR in a while :). Updated the answer.